# The you, not you the person, but the _____ you?

Tags: single-word-requests

I've heard this line before in movies and conversations, but I'm experiencing lethologica with this word. And I can't seem to google search it anywhere.

It's supposed to mean like the `<general masses>` or a much wider audience than the current context.

I am not too sure how the question format at *English SE* is supposed to be, so I'm all ears if the question needs/can be formatted!

Comment: You guys? You people? Y'all?

Comment: It's a single word, I feel like it was `primordial` but not quite sure.

Comment: The "plural" you? It's not very clear what concept you're searching for.

Comment: O ye ............

Comment: In the context of the movie, it was used to deflect an accusation. The dialogue was something like `I didn't mean you, I was referring to the _____ you. Because all of us experience it at some point`. Is that helpful?

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion it was the *proverbial you*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found it, after asking around. The saying goes as:

> Not you, I mean the **proverbial** you!

Sorry if my question wasn't clear enough!